# ProgressDialog doesn't up while preparing another AlertDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a AlertDialog which the content may takes around 5 seconds to prepare the content data. During waiting for the AlertDialog to show up, I'm trying to add a ProgressDialog while waiting it, but somehow the ProgressDialog doesn't show up, it only flash like one second before the AlertDialog was ready.

Appreciate for helps.

```
final DialogFragment newFragment = setApplicationFragment.newInstance();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {  
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "alert");
                pd.dismiss();  
                return;  
            }  
        }).start();
```

Comment: Actually we can't use the dialog box inside the thread it shows the error.

Comment: If u r doing something in UI thread, ProgressDialog wont show up. You can consider other alternatives like AsynTask in which u can show ProgressDialg while doing background tasks

Comment: Tried ASyncTask, same result.